# Analyse SQL Scan Performance

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a question about the SQL scan performance. No index exists.

```
select id from customer where age <45;
select id from customer where salary >40,000;
select id from customer where sex = 'Male';
```

The running time are  22.136, 87.435, 132.242 ms. Both of them are ruined by 10 times and take average.

My question: 1. Why the first query is significant faster than second one, given that they both perform scan.
2. Why the third one is the slowest? Is it because it is related to character checking?
3. What factors I should consider?

Theory-level answers are appreciated(Since there are too many random events in engineering).

Comment: Do you have any indices on these columns?  Have you tried using `EXPLAIN` on these queries to view the execution plan?

Comment: I usd `/timing` rather than `EXPLAIN`. Is it true that the latter output the estimated time? I notice that the estimated time is much shorter than `/timing`.

Comment: I don't like the idea of trying to benchmark these queries by just running a few local tests.  `EXPLAIN` will show you how the query is scheduled and executed, and something might jump out at you there.

Comment: Thanks! I just did several `EXPLAIN`. They shows both of them are Seq Scan. Query plan is also empty. Confused.

Comment: Add the output of  `explain (analyze, buffers)` and the definition of the table including all indexes. http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Answer (score 2):

All three queries should have the same execution plan.  For detailed timings, you should be sure that the cache is uninitialized.

Assuming your timings are correct, they are probably driven by the size of the returned data set.  The larger amount of data being returned, the longer the query will probably take.